# MSSQL and PHP Advanced Search Engine not Querying Properly

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, forms, search

I have an advanced, yet simple, PHP search engine for my MSSQL table `products`. The search engine has three text inputs. The first input is for the `make` column of the table, the second is for the `product_name` column of the table, and the last is for my `material` column from the table. My problem, from what I can see, is that when I leave two inputs blank and type in `valve`, the query should echo `SELECT * FROM products WHERE 1=1 AND product_name = 'valve'`. Instead, the query is echoing `SELECT * FROM products WHERE 1=1`. I don't know why that is happening, and I think I could use another set of eyes to figure out this issue.

Here is the full PHP code:

```
<form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="post">
      <input type="text"   name="make">
      <input type="text"   name="parttype">
      <input type="text"   name="material">
      <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
$conn = mssql_connect('gdm','ger','Rr1!');
mssql_select_db('Ggler',$conn);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$cheack = "";

if(isset($_GET["make"])&&$_GET["make"] != ""){
    $make = $_POST['make'];
    $cheack.="  AND make =  '$make' ";
}

if(isset($_GET["parttype"])&&$_GET["parttype"] != ""){
    $parttype = $_POST['parttype'];
    $cheack.="  AND product_name =  '$parttype' ";
}

if(isset($_GET["material"])&&$_GET["material"] != ""){
    $material = $_POST['material'];
    $cheack.="  AND material =  '$material' ";
}

   $DB = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE 1=1 ".$cheack;
   $runquery = mssql_query($DB, $conn);
   $dad =  mssql_fetch_assoc($runquery);
   echo "".$DB."";
}else { 
    echo "No search made"; }
?>
```

Thank you for any help. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: check your code... &&$ should have space && $

Comment: Apparently not, as it still works without the space.

Comment: didn't even notive the post/get issue pointed out by @Marc B... I'd still leave the space though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spot the problem:

```
<form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="post">
                                           ^^^^^

if(isset($_GET["make"])&&$_GET["make"] != ""){
          ^^^^            ^^^^
```

As well, you are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).